# Config Git to not require comment every checkin

Tags: git, egit, git-gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git commit with no commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218199/git-commit-with-no-commit-message)

I am looking for a way to configure Git to not require a comment upon checkins.  I hope it can be done on the repository side but if it is a client setting, that's OK.  I will mostly be using the Eclipse plugin but may use Git GUI from time to time.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? commit messages are an easy way to find a certain point in time in a repo and having no message or the same message seems to defeat that purpose.

Comment: ah. From experience, 4-6 months down the road you won't remember what happened when or for what reason.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "checkin" in Git, and you shouldn't do what you're trying to do. Useful commit messages are a Good Thing. @RDL Back to work, jerk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes against good version control practices, however this should do it for you:

```
git commit -a --allow-empty-message -m ''
```