# trouble in using "git commit -a" command

Tags: repository, git-commit, git

I am trying to commit all my changes by using following command

```
git commit -a
```

Note : I want to commit without any "commit message"

but when I execute above command it shows me the screen shown below, and I don't know how to get out of this screen to complete my commit.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to commit without a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify a commit message with each commit.  There are two ways to do this.  First, you can provide it on the command line, using the `-m` switch:

```
git commit -am "I made the changes"
```

If you don't specify that switch, git opens the configured editor.  By default, this is vim.  To write the message in vim, type <kbd>i</kbd> to enter *insert mode*, then type your message.  Hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit *insert mode*, then type `:wq` to save (**w**rite) and **q**uit the editor.

You can also [configure another editor to be used by git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/2688).  On the command line, you can run a command like `git config --global core.editor notepad`, where `notepad` is the name of the editor that you prefer.

Comment: is there a way to commit without message?

Comment: No, there is no way to commit without a message.  Commits require a message.  It can be something as simple as 'Changed 4 files', or 'Another update'.  That said, having meaningful commit messages is _really_ helpful to make sense of source control when you come back to a project later (even a couple of days later).

Answer (score 2):

try `git commit -a -m '[your commit message]'`

edit: git need always a comment for each commit, you can by the way add an empty comment with

```
git commit -a -m ''
```

or

```
git commit -am ''
```

Committing with a message is necessary when using Git, but is also helpful:

Crafting the commit message is a very important step of your development work. The message is usually the first thing other developers will see, and the first line in a Git commit-msg has a special meaning. It is considered the "Title" or "Subject" of the commit. Many interfaces use this title to represent the commit, such as:

-Subject of e-mail notifications

-git log's "oneline" mode

-Gerrit interface (dashboard, search results, title)

-Git revert (cites the commit title)

-Various Git GUI clients

(use first line as title until first empty line or end of body)

Comment: I want to commit without any message

Comment: then you can do: git commit -a -m ''

Answer (score 0):

u should use `git commit -a -m '[your message here]'`

a commit message is necessary you can keep it empty as well

`git commit -a -m ''`

a correlated question

[Git commit with no commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218199/git-commit-with-no-commit-message)

Comment: I want to commit without any message

Comment: git commit need a message. you can give an empty message. have given the reference of another question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified commit message so Git opened default editor (Vim in this case) to specify message. You have 2 options to solve this:

1. Write your message writeing

   ```
   i{your message}<ESC>:wq<CR>
   ```
2. Or write message directly into command line:

   ```
   git commit -am 'your message'
   ```