# git revert HEAD is opening the nano editor. How can I avoid this?

Tags: git, terminal, revert

Whenever I try to revert a commit using git revert, terminal opens up the nano editor. The revert goes through, but I have to esc out of nano. Is there a way to prevent git from doing that?

On a similar note, is there a way to prevent git from forcing me to add a message whenever I commit something?

Thanks!

Comment: You want it to open a different editor instead?

Comment: +1 to @tom-leu's answer. My personal opinion is if you don't want to bother with good commit messages then there really isn't a good reason to use source control. Backups and journaling work just fine and they are commit message free.

Comment: If nano is the problem here, you can either set vim as the editor in your .bashrc, or just uninstall nano (which makes linux pick up vim automatically)

Comment: I don't mind writing commit messages. I didn't know how to revert and include a message at the same time so I was getting annoyed at the editor popping off. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the core editor check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits) which explains how.

Making commits without a message is considered a bad practice, especially if you are pushing those commits to shared repositories. [This article](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) and [this article](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/) explain why commit messages are important and some best practices for writing them.

If you still want to have empty commits then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218199/git-commit-with-no-commit-message) explains how.

Comment: Thanks @Sukima, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the links for better commit messages. I didn't know how to git revert and add a comment at the same time so I was getting annoyed that nano was popping off whenever I used the revert command.

Edit: I ended up using " git revert --no-edit <commit> " to avoid having the editor pop off.

Comment: @yazami `git revert --no-commit` Then you can commit manually after, giving you the chance to look at your files before you commit.